# How to return variable to *ngFor?

Tags: angular, ionic2

Just started learning ionic2 and Angular. This is what i have inside the member.ts file

```
Events (eventData) {
  return this.storage.get('signature').then((val) => {
    this.getDataApi.getEventData(val, function (data) {
      if (data.events.length > 0)  {
          //console.log(data.events);
          eventData = data.events;
          console.log(eventData);
          return eventData;

        }
      })
    })
}
```

inside console.log(eventData) i have [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object] return. Just couldn't display within the "let item of eventData" side.

I am trying to display the payload in member.html. Still very new to this. Anyone

```
<button ion-item *ngFor="let item of eventData" (click)="gotoEvent($event, name)">
  {{item.name}}
</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

`eventData` needs to be instance property instead of global variable:

```javascript
this.getDataApi.getEventData(val, (data) => {
  if (data.events.length > 0)  {
      //console.log(data.events);
      this.eventData = data.events; // <-- use this.eventData = ...
      return eventData;
    }
  })
})
```

Also, note that you should use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) so that `this` has correct reference inside callback.

Comment: He should remove the `return` in that case

Comment: @YounesM Yes, most likely return is not needed. But I also see `return this.storage.get('signature')` so who knows how OP uses this method since it returns promise.

Comment: Got stuck for 2 days! thank you TounesM and dfsq ! it is now working! Still now very familiar with the arrow function syntax. Wil go and read up more! Thank you so much!